# Is it possible to use a class in a header file without including it, while also using that same class in the cpp file?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am trying to use a class from a closed-source C++ library (only have access to the header files) from a different language, but the bindings generator fails when including the class' header files. Because of this, I need to write a C++ wrapper for that library, but I can't include the class' header file in my wrapper's header file, because bindgen will fail if it's included.

Is there a way to use a class in a header file that isn't included while also allowing that header file to be read on its own (maybe using `typedef` or `extern`)?

Example of the setup I would ideally want:

`CompiledCode.hpp`

```
class Foo {
    ...
}
```

`wrapper.hpp`

```
// Magic to allow me to use the class name Foo as a return type

Foo createFoo();
```

`wrapper.cpp`

```cpp
#include "CompiledCode.hpp"
#include "wrapper.hpp"

Foo createFoo() {
    return Foo::create();
}
```

Comment: Forward declaration is enough in wrapper.hpp, but user would need its definition.

Comment: There is no need for magic, a forward declaration will suffice. However, you won't be able to *use* `createFoo` without including the full definition of `Foo`.

Comment: If user should know nothing about `Foo`, then return `Foo*` and provide also a deleter. (and you can provide a c++ wrapper for c++ users).

Comment: ...how did I not find this while searching online on and off for a week and a half?
I will attempt to get it working now

Comment: yep, got it working