# Use typedef from header file that isn't #included as a return type

Tags: c++

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712305/is-it-possible-to-use-a-class-in-a-header-file-without-including-it-while-also).

I need to use a typedef from a header file (`original.h`) as a return type in another header which doesn't have access to `original.h`. To complicate things further, this typedef is nested inside a class. I've tried directly copypasting the typedef, but the return types don't match in the cpp file (which does have access to `original.h`).

Is there a way to either cast between identical typedefs or forward-declare a typedef (from searching up online the second one seems impossible, but maybe something could work considering it will only be used as a return type)?

Edit: full typedef:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        #ifdef __vxworks
        unsigned Comm : 8;
        unsigned Mode : 8;
        unsigned RSL : 1;
        #else
        unsigned RSL : 1;
        unsigned Mode : 8;
        unsigned Comm : 8;
        #endif
    };
    struct
    {
        unsigned value : 17;
    };
} tLEDs;
```

Comment: Copy-pasting the definition does the same thing as `#include`ing the header that defines it. The benefit of using the header is that if the definition changes you only have to update one copy of it.

Comment: @PeteBecker issue is (this is a wrapper for a closed-source library) when I call functions from the original class, it returns that header file's version of the typedef. Which doesn't work, because the typedef in the wrapper header file isn't in the same namespace/class. I have it in the same namespace, but can't put it in the same class b/c that class is also being forward-declared.

Comment: You have to provide the complete definition of the type.

Comment: @PeteBecker I edited the full typedef into the question, I'm pretty sure it includes all relevant information. I haven't really used C++ before though, so I could be wrong

Comment: The whole thing sounds horribly misguided, but you *can* use `std::bit_cast` to do what you are asking for, I guess.

Comment: I feel like I should just ask a general question about the best way to go about this, as I'm leaving out a lot of context - and yeah, `bit_cast` seems pretty scuffed so I'd prefer any alternate solutions that might be possible with context lol

Comment: Sorry, when I said "You have to..." I was referring to the code where you use that type. Pulling in a definition with a `#include` directive copies the code; copying the code yourself does the same thing. The compiler doesn't care whether the definition of the type came from a `#include` directive or from the code that you wrote. Just make sure that the definition that you write is identical to the definition that the headers provide.

Comment: Yeah, the definition is identical but it’s not in the same class. I assume that’s the problem

Comment: @PeteBecker would there be a way to define a conversion between the two typedefs (as my IDE says there's no suitable user-defined conversation)

Comment: If the two typedefs are the same they’re the same. No conversion needed. If the compiler wants to convert it’s because the definitions are different. If the definition is not in the same class then it’s not the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just manually writing a function to copy all fields of the struct, i.e. for this problem:

```cpp
LEDs tleds_to_leds(tLEDs tleds)
{
    LEDs leds;
    leds.rsl = tleds.RSL;
    leds.mode = tleds.Mode;
    leds.comm = tleds.Comm;
    leds.value = tleds.value;
    return leds;
}
```